# Disable iCloud backup for NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults, icloud

This is probably a weird thing for me to want to do, but how does one disable the backup of NSUserDefaults to the cloud?

I have used this successfully for data that can be redownloaded from the server, but looking for a way to use it against NSUserDefaults.

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why not just use a different storage system that you have more control over? Saving an `NSDictionary` to a `plist` file for example.

Comment: Everything is already made. I figured it may be easier to disable sync with NSUserDefaults rather than retrofitting the project with an NSDictionary... If its not possible, then NSDictionary would be appropriate.

Comment: Also operations like "check if run for first time" don't reliably work since NSUserDefaults comes back when you restore your phone. What are your thoughts on that? Thanks. For the purposes of my app, restoring the phone needs to count as a first time run so that it may fetch data from the server.

Comment: He duplicated mine, I asked first ;-)